# mobile foundation adapter logs not available on bluemix

Tags: logging, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using the IBM Mobile Foundation Bluemix service. I have a JavaScript HTTP adapter that has some log statements using `MFP.Logger.info()`. When I hit my adapter with Swagger, cURL, or the application, I can never see these logs. When I look in Bluemix console under the "Logs" tab or when I use `cf logs {appName}` the only log messages I see are

`2016-10-06T13:18:43.57-0400 [App/0]      OUT [INFO    ] Cloud : Getting Local MBeans`

and all of the HTTP requests that are being made. I can never find the debug statements. I have read through https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/bluemix/using-mobile-foundation/ but this just shows how to access the logs on Bluemix.

Is there some setting or something I need to do to see my standard log statements in my JavaScript HTTP adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify in a devkit installation that `MFP.Logger.info` goes to the **messages.log** file, located in the **{devkit-installation-folder}/mfp-server/usrs/servers/mfp/logs** folder.

Another option for you to try, in the Mobile Foundation Bluemix service, is to [forward the adapter logs to the Analytics server](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/server-side-log-collection/javascript-adapter/). For this, you'll need to [enable analytics](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/bluemix/using-mobile-foundation/#adding-analytics-support) in the service.